# Unusual results returned by df, what caused it, how to fix?

Tags: unix, solaris

Here is a copy-paste:

```
root@****#df -h /var
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/md/dsk/d4         9.8G  8192E     0K 90204286294657% /var
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please post `cat /etc/release` output.

Answer (score 2):

The `df` command uses the `statfs` system call to find out the actual status of the filesystem usage. This `statfs` system call uses the actual filesystem driver of the given filesystem, which uses this information from the filesystem metadata on the hard disk.

I am nearly sure, that your problem is that this filesystem metadata on your hard disk is broken.

In short: the filesystem on your disk `/dev/md/dsk/d4` is corrupt. You need to fix that. If it is an ext2-3-4 filesystem, you can do that with an `e2fsck -f -y -C0 /dev/md/dsk/4` . Good luck!

(Of course you had to unmount the filesystem before doing that.)

Comment: Don't do this while the file system is mounted!

Comment: @MadHatter Of course, thanks! I extended my answer.

Comment: This is a Solaris platform, there is no ext2-3-4 support with it. It is also very unlikely due to a file system corruption but almost certainly due to an ancient `df` bug.

Answer (score 1):

The statistics reported by `df` are obviously bogus.

The root cause is likely a Solaris 10 `df` bug that was fixed around eight years ago.

You should make sure you are up to date with patches !